# Why doesn't a table-cell styled element without explicit width stretch to fill the remaining width of a table/table-row styled parent?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Can someone explain why the two table layouts below aren't the same (specifically, why the second 'table-cell' div doesn't stretch to take up the rest of the width of the 'table' parent div, as it does in the real table)?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 20px;">.</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red;">.</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 20px;">.</div>
        </div>
        <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 0;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">.</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid red;">.</td>
                <td style="width: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: turns out you get some unexpected behaviour if you try and style an image as a table-cell:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
* {border: 1px solid black;}
table, .table, .row {
    width: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
img {
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
}
    ]]></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="cell" />
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="cell" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The 2nd cell-styled div doesn't stretch all the way horizontally to fill the rest of the table width. If you add content to it, it gradually does though. Weird.

Comment: Because you haven't given your parent div a `display:table` rule?

Comment: True in this test case, oops! I was simplifying my source with the actual issue and seems I inadvertently removed that rule and ended up oversimplifying the problem code as a result! Working on an updated demo of the issue...

Comment: Yeah, images don't turn into table-cell elements very well.  For what its worth, there's a lot of overlap between tables and the Flexbox module.  Because only the parent element is required to have its display type modified, it plays very well with images (see: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Azone).

Answer (score 10):

Unless the a table-cell element's parent is a table-row element (and its parent element is a table element) or table element, anonymous table and table-row elements are inserted for you.  Anonymous elements cannot be styled.

If you want your table-cell elements to take up the entire available width, you need to make an explicit table element to contain them for styling purposes.

http://tinker.io/29b92

```
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 20px;">.</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red;">.</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 20px;">.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was 'images don't reliably style as table-cells', but I mis-simplified my initial test case. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

You should work with tables inside other tables if you want one of your rows to expand to the same width.

Also, if your parent table is 100%, your child table can't be 100% as well, have you tried 98%?

Style your HTML in and external CSS file to prevent repeating your clause every line.

If that doesn't work, let me know and i will keep looking for more options you can try.

Comment: It can be 100% of its parent's width unless it's being obstructed by borders and/or padding.

Comment: True, although in the example there is a 1px border every time. That might give you a problem. Although cimmanon has already given a more valid answer to the question. Thanks!